# Accidentally split / mirrored tmux screen

Tags: tmux, macos

I must have pressed something. My `tmux` view split into two panes (?) and both show the same thing. If I type in the bottom one, it's typed in the top one too.

I detached from it and attached again. Now the top pane says `[detached (from session 0)]` and the bottom pane is working normally.

How do I close the top pane? (And what did I press?)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Good point, edited in a question. I want to get rid of the top thing. Now I think it's not a pane actually. I can Ctrl-B " to split into panes horizontally. Those are separated by a narrow line. (And have different content and I can close them with Ctrl-D.) But the top thing is separated by a thicker gray line.

Comment: But it's not a window or a session either. What else does `tmux` have? I'm so lost. I'd prefer not to restart the whole thing because I have a bunch of things running.

Answer (score 2):

It was not `tmux`! I had accidentally pressed ⌘-D and split the macOS Terminal window.

Comment: I did learn a lot from reading through the `tmux` documentation though!

Comment: I did the exact same thing. Came here after a "tmux i managed to split window mirrored" google search, but it turned out I had split the macOS iTerm window. Thanks for your question (and answer), saved me reading through the `tmux` documentation!